# Client occassionally does not detect hangup and so does not reconnect

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, signalr

I'm using SignalR in .Net 3.5 (the RC of SignalR), and I'm finding that about once per day, when using longpolling as the transport, it connects, but then never detects a timeout, remaining in a "connected" state despite the connection already being close.

Normally it reconnects every 2 minutes, but after doing this for ~ a day, it just connects, then never disconnect/reconnects.

Aside from a watchdog timer to check for this, is there anything else I might look at?  I'm using a pretty vanilla SignalR client implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SignalR Client (btw .NET 35 is no longer supported), doesn't detect client side disconnects. That logic will be added post 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info, noticed that it disappeared from GitHub a couple of days ago :P  Awesome work!